# Creating a new columns from existing in Python

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe in Python named "final"

| purchase_date | Expiration_date | is_trial_period | current_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-10-12. | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-06. |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-06. |
| 2021-10-04 | 2021-11-04. | TRUE | 2021-10-06. |

The datatypes of final dataframe are+

```
purchase_date:datetime64[ns]
,Expiration_date:datetime64[ns]
,is_trial_period:object
,current_date:datetime64[ns],
dtype: object
```

I want to create a new column called XYZ.

1. If is_trail_period is FALSE & Expiration_date >= current_date, the value of XYZ column should be 'Active Subscription' else 'Expired Subscription'
2. If is_trail_period is TRUE & Expiration_date >= current_date, the value of XYZ column should be 'Active TRIAL' else 'Expired TRIAL'

How can I do that in Python ??

I tried doing

```
def func(row):
    if ((bool(final['is_trial_period'])== 'FALSE') & (final['Expiration_date'] >= final['current_date'])):
        return 'Active Subscription'
    elif ((bool(final['is_trial_period'])== 'FALSE') & (final['Expiration_date'] < final['current_date'])):
        return 'Expired Subscription'
    elif ((bool(final['is_trial_period'])== 'TRUE') & (final['Expiration_date'] >= final['current_date'])):
        return 'Active Trial'
    elif ((bool(final['is_trial_period'])== 'FALSE') & (final['Expiration_date'] < final['current_date'])):
        return 'Expired Trial'

final['XYZ'] = final.apply(func, axis=1)
```

But then I am getting an error
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

I want my final output to be like

| purchase_date | Expiration_date | is_trial_period | current_date. | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-0 | Expired Subscription |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-06 | Expired Subscription |
| 2021-10-04 | 2021-11-04 | TRUE | 2021-10-06 | Active Trial |

Comment: if possible share the dataframe

Comment: The 'final' dataframe is the table above without XYZ columns. I dont know why I am not able to get it in table format at the start of the question. @Sabil

Comment: @Sabil Did you get it

Comment: Please share final.to_dict() for ease for others.

Comment: yes, i got it. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should call `row` instead of `final`. Also remove unnecessary `bool` conversion and it all set to go.

**Try this:**

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'purchase_date': ['2013-10-12', '2013-10-12', '2021-10-04'],
    'expiration_date': ['2013-12-12', '2013-12-12', '2021-11-04'],
    'is_trial_period': ['FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'],
    'current_date': ['2021-10-06', '2021-10-06', '2021-10-06']
}

def func(row):
    if row['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE' and row['expiration_date'] >= row['current_date']:
        return 'Active Subscription'
    elif row['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE' and row['expiration_date'] < row['current_date']:
        return 'Expired Subscription'
    elif row['is_trial_period']== 'TRUE' and row['expiration_date'] >= row['current_date']:
        return 'Active Trial'
    elif row['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE' and row['expiration_date'] < row['current_date']:
        return 'Expired Trial'

final = pd.DataFrame(data)
final['XYZ'] = final.apply(func, axis=1)

print(final)
```

**Output:**

```
  purchase_date expiration_date is_trial_period current_date                   XYZ
0    2013-10-12      2013-12-12           FALSE   2021-10-06  Expired Subscription
1    2013-10-12      2013-12-12           FALSE   2021-10-06  Expired Subscription
2    2021-10-04      2021-11-04            TRUE   2021-10-06          Active Trial
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:
First, I cleaned your dataframe a bit. Removed the . after `current_date` and fix the `current_date` value in first row as the day is not given.

```
final["XYZ"] = ""

for index in final.index:
    if (final.loc[index, "is_trial_period"] == False) & (final.loc[index,"Expiration_date"] >= final.loc[index,"current_date"]):
        final.loc[index,"XYZ"] = "Active Subscription"
    elif (final.loc[index, "is_trial_period"] == False) & (final.loc[index,"Expiration_date"] < final.loc[index,"current_date"]):
        final.loc[index,"XYZ"] = "Expired Subscription"
    elif (final.loc[index, "is_trial_period"] == True) & (final.loc[index,"Expiration_date"] >= final.loc[index,"current_date"]):
        final.loc[index,"XYZ"] = "Active Trial"
    else:
        final.loc[index,"XYZ"] = "Expired Trial"
final
```

Results looks like this:

```
purchase_date   Expiration_date is_trial_period current_date    XYZ
0   2013-10-12  2013-12-12  False   2021-10-06  Expired Subscription
1   2013-10-12  2013-12-12  False   2021-10-06  Expired Subscription
2   2021-10-04  2021-11-04  True    2021-10-06  Active Trial
```

Answer (score 0):

I will generally use `df.loc` to solve these kind of issues.

```
final.loc[(final['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE') & (final['expiration_date'] >= final['current_date']), 'XYZ'] = 'Active Subscription'
final.loc[(final['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE') & (final['expiration_date'] < final['current_date']), 'XYZ'] = 'Expired Subscription'
final.loc[(final['is_trial_period'] == 'TRUE') & (final['expiration_date'] >= final['current_date']), 'XYZ'] = 'Active Trial'
final.loc[(final['is_trial_period'] == 'TRUE') & (final['expiration_date'] < final['current_date']), 'XYZ'] = 'Expired Trial'
```

[image]

Comment: This is my Pandas way of handling new columns...generally speaking.